# MS Excel help using function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data with 4 columns

I want to put two conditions on two different columns (column 1 and column 2) and if both conditions met then need their corresponding columns (column 3 & column 4) values.

I want it using excel functions only (not using sort & filter tab).
Is there any way to do?

[image: example]

IF in column1 (BAC US) and in column 2 (B) it should give 444 in C3 and 9.825 in C4. Same for 4th row

Comment: I am trying to get a data , if the data in Column A and B exist then it should give me Column C and D.(which are corressponding to it using excel functions)

Comment: Confusing... Can you clear up exactly what is the condition? If data is in column A, or if data in column a _is_ `BAC US`? Does it matter what's in column A when you look at column B? Does the formula in column C change based on _what_ is in column A or column B or only if there is _anything_ in column A and column B?

Comment: Where do you want the results from these If statements to appear? It looks like columns 1-4 already have data, and instead of using Filter you want equations to give you a summary. Is that right? Should this summary be on a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

The way IF is used is:

```
IF(condition, do this, otherwise do this)
```

You can find more about it here: [IF function - Microsoft Excel](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

If "BAC US" is in cell A1 and you wanted to change C1 and D1 you'd put the following in cell C1:

```
IF(A1="BAC US", "444")
```

and then this, in D1:

```
IF(A1="BAC US", "9.825")
```

I don't know what you want it to do otherwise but if you want to leave it "0" otherwise, you'd leave an unfollowed comma, like so:

C1:

```
IF(A1="BAC US", "444",)
```

D1:

```
IF(A1="BAC US", "9.825",)
```

Otherwise, it'll just say "FALSE".

Since you want to check 2 separate cells in one IF, I'd recommend using the AND function. For more information on the AND function, see: [AND Function - Microsoft Excel](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9)

To use it in your case, you'd put the following in C1 and D1:

C1:

```
IF((AND(A1="BAC US", B1="B")), "444",)
```

D1:

```
IF((AND(A1="BAC US", B1="B")), "444",)
```